# onclick of a radio button display/hide the contents

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Right now I have a functionality in a jsp page: when yes radio button is selcted and the form is saved  it displays span(this function working perfectly).

```
<s:if test="%{test ==Y}" > 
    //displaying span
```

But now I have a new requirement when  people try to update a form and if they select no radio button the span should disapear and vice versa. I tried to this with JS but its not firing any event. please help me out I must hide/show span when they click yes/no radio button

```js
function bet() {
    var test_1 = document.getElementsByName('test');
    if (test_1[0].checked) {
        document.getElementById('testing').style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    if (!test_1[0].checked) {
        document.getElementById('testing').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

```html
Yes<input type="radio" name="test" title="yes" onClick="bet()" value="Y">
No<input type="radio" name="test" title="NO" onClick="bet()" value="N">

<span id="testing">This is a test</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  // get radio options
  var options = document.getElementsByName('test'),
      // ref content
      content = document.getElementById('testing'),
      // ref content display prop
      originalDisplayStyle = content.style.display;

  options.forEach(function(option){
    // listen for onclick event
    option.addEventListener('click', function(){
      var display = this.value === 'N' && this.checked ? 'none' : originalDisplayStyle;
      // hide/show content based on selection
      content.style.display = display;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
Yes<input type="radio" name="test" title="yes" value="Y">
No<input type="radio" name="test" title="NO" value="N">


<span id="testing">This is a test</span>
```

Comment: hey dysfunc thank you very much man you are a life saver. I was lost for many hours trying to find a solution. thanks again and god bless u

Comment: glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind **onclick** with radio elements.

```
var radioBtn = document.getElementsByName('test');

for (var i = 0, len = radioBtn.length; i < len; i++) {
  radioBtn[i].onclick = function() {

    if (this.value === 'Y') {
      document.getElementById('testing').style.visibility = "visible";    
    } else {
      document.getElementById('testing').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

  }
}
```